# Get full content from current word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS-Word `.docm` document with a macro inside. In this macro I want to get the full content from the document as a ***byte array***. The content should contain the full information of the document and when I save this content I should be able to open this file in Word again.

Im totally new to `vba` and don't have any idea where to start. I thought about saving the document in a temp folder to read this file to get the content but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use

```
ThisDocument.SaveAs "c:\temp\mydoc.docm"
```

Then simply use that file for your further operation.

Or to print out your file as bytes:

```
Sub SaveAsByteArray()
    Dim thisFile  As String
    thisFile = ActiveDocument.FullName
    Dim targetFile As String
    targetFile = "C:\temp\doc.docm"
    Dim sourceFileNum As Integer
    Dim targetFileNum  As Integer

    Dim aByte As Byte

    sourceFileNum = FreeFile
    Open thisFile For Random Access Read As sourceFileNum Len = 1

    targetFileNum = FreeFile
    Open targetFile For Random Access Write As targetFileNum Len = 1

    Do While Not EOF(sourceFileNum)
        Get #sourceFileNum, , aByte
        Put #targetFileNum, , aByte
    Loop

    Close sourceFileNum
    Close targetFileNum
End Sub
```

But this sub adds an extra byte at the end, so Excel will open a dialog asking if you want to fix the contents. If you choose yes, then word is able to open the file.

Or put it into an array:

```
Sub SaveAsByteArray()
    Dim thisFile  As String
    thisFile = ActiveDocument.FullName
    Dim sourceFileNum As Integer

    Dim arr()
    Dim arr_n as long
    arr_n = 0

    Dim aByte As Byte

    sourceFileNum = FreeFile
    Open thisFile For Random Access Read As sourceFileNum Len = 1

    Do While Not EOF(sourceFileNum)
        Get #sourceFileNum, , aByte

        ReDim Preserve arr(0 to arr_n)
        arr(arr_n) = aByte
        arr_n=arr_n+1

    Loop

    Close sourceFileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Currently I'm using 'ActiveDocument.Save' to save the file because I don't want to show a Dialog.But I don't have any idea how to read the content as byte array.

Comment: I added a semi-solution to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can save the current document in another file with your solution but I need it as a byte array.Can I use the put methode to write in an array or stream as well?

Comment: @Nergal: here you are